# OpenCL subdevice affinity not respected by scheduler

Tags: c, windows, opencl, partition, numa

I'm trying to write an OpenCL proof of concept application that executes a kernel on a specific CPU (and thus can be extended in the future to be NUMA-aware and allocate the memory for the kernel execution on the corresponding NUMA-node, as pointed out [in the Intel Dev forums](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/497429)).

Unfortunately the Windows scheduler doesn't care what I want, as it seems to circle my kernel through all available CPU cores (thus away from the local memory).

I'm right now using the `CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS` property to create a single subdevice with only one execution unit and I'm then executing the kernel on this one subdevice. Nonetheless, when I'm watching the CPU usage of Windows, it's not that a single core is busy, but multiple cores have spikes in their workload (unless I manually pin the process to one core using the task manager - then I get the result I expected all along).

Here is the full definition of the properties I used to create the subdevice (if I query the number of execution units of the subdevice it correctly gives me "1"):

```
cl_device_partition_property props[4];
props[0] = CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS;
props[1] = 1;
props[2] = CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS_LIST_END;
props[3] = 0;
```

I'm using a Windows machine with two Intel Xeon processors (which are by the way recognized as one execution device with 24 execution unites by the Intel OpenCL implementation) and did also try to use `CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_NAMES_INTEL`, which didn't work out either).

What am I doing wrong (or understanding the wrong way)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using any of these flags?

```
CL_AFFINITY_DOMAIN_L1_CACHE_EXT                 0x1
CL_AFFINITY_DOMAIN_L2_CACHE_EXT                 0x2
CL_AFFINITY_DOMAIN_L3_CACHE_EXT                 0x3
CL_AFFINITY_DOMAIN_L4_CACHE_EXT                 0x4
CL_AFFINITY_DOMAIN_NUMA_EXT                     0x10
CL_AFFINITY_DOMAIN_NEXT_FISSIONABLE_EXT         0x100
```

I think when you use CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_COUNTS, you are asking for any single core to do the work. The flags above will try to group based on cache levels, which is your objective anyway. I haven't tested this myself to see if the OS will honor the affinity, but i expect that it should do so. [read more here.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/ext/cl_ext_device_fission.txt)

Comment: Yes, I tried using those. Unfortunately, neither the Intel OpenCL SDK nor the AMD OpenCL SDK (/ drivers) seem to currently support affinity domains.